# \hhline only drawing horizontal lines

Tags: hhline

I cannot seem to make `\hhline` draw vertical lines between cells.  What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  A & B \\ \hhline{~|-}
  C & D \\ \hhline{~|-|}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What do you try to obtain?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. `\hhline` is defined to produce only horizontal lines (the "h" in the command).  If you want vertical lines separating all the cells, enter the template as `{c|c}`.  If you want them on the outside edges as well, use `{|c|c|}`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I don't want vertical lines in the template as I don't want vertical lines around all cells, only some.

Comment: @Tom I don't think you can do that.

Comment: You would need to do this weird thing, and even then it only works on the rightmost edge.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`-` makes a single line, you need `=` to get separated double line

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|}
  A & B \\ \hhline{~|=}
  C & D \\ \hhline{~|=|}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle My PDF does not show the vertical lines regardless of whether I use '-' or '='.  Am thinking something specific to my system is wrong.  Never had an issue like this.

Comment: @Tom the vertical lines _within the `\hhline`_ naturally only show if you have a double line so `=` rather than `-`. the vertical lines around the table cells so around  B abd D are totally unrelated to `\hhline` and come from the table preamble, `{c|c|}` in this case.